# Enumerated features in TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, tensor

Let's say that I want an input feature to my neural net to be the day of the week on which the other features were registered. Our customers behave noticeably differently on each day of the week, so I think this is appropriate.

How can I represent this sort of feature within a `tf.placeholder` Should I just pass it as an int, or is there a better way to do this that includes the inherent limitation (always between 0 and 6...)

We also have a "customer type" feature that would be similar - hoping there's some way to reduce a `tf.int8` to a `tf.enum`

Apologies if this is a dumb or irrelevant question... just learning TF now and thought that this might help with training.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, seems like I can do this later in the process by stuffing a [categorical_column_with_identity](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/categorical_column_with_identity) into an [indicator_column](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column/indicator_column)